# onSurfaceCreated not working for gl calls

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

I am working on an android app using the Cardboard SDK.

My `MainActivity` extends `CardboardActivity` and implements `CardboardView.StereoRenderer`, pretty much following the Google tutorial.

I have noticed, however, that OpenGL calls inside my `onSurfaceCreated` override have no effect, for instance, if I call `GLES20.glClearColor(...)` inside `onSurfaceCreated`, the clear color remains black. However, if I call `glClearColor` inside `onNewFrame` or `onDrawEye`, the clear color changes to what I have called.

Two things I noticed:

1) the signature the IDE has suggested is `public void onSurfaceCreated(EGLConfig eglConfig)`, whereas I noticed on my search on Google that there is an `onSurfaceCreated(GL10, EGLConfig)`... Did the signature change?

2) I get six consecutive reports on the log window saying

> E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once
>   per thread)

before my `onSurfaceCreated` is even called(I logged when each of my functions are called). I don't think this is the cause of the error since when I move the `glClearColor` call to `onNewFrame` it works, but maybe someone can point me to something else I'm doing wrong.

So my question is, why can't I get OpenGL calls in my `onSurfaceCreated` function to have any effect?

Comment: sounds like `onSurfaceCreated` is not being called from the same thread your GL context is on

Answer (score 0):

Observed the same. And it seems like it's a quite old bug (https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/issues/9). Doesn't look like it's fixed yet but maybe it's the only function call that doesn't work. Have you checked that?

Okay, I've checked it and it seems like only the glClearColor function is affected. Tried to create a shader inside onSurfaceCreated and it all went well.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Somehow I feel better knowing it's not something wrong on my part! I'll check if it's the only function that doesn't work, if not I'll just create a first time test inside onNewFrame... not the best solution but what the heck...